# HttpClient Authorization Header Invalid Format

Tags: c#, authorization, dotnet-httpclient

When I try to make a `GET` request with the address and Authorization value below, I have no problems.

Address: http://example.com/xyz.svc/branches/?latitude=0&longitude=0&range=20000

Header Key:  Authorization

Value:       example;foo

When I try it with `HttpCLient` I get format invalid error for the authorization header value

This is how I tried

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    string latitude = "0";
    string longitude = "0";
    string range = "2000";

    string uri = "/xyz.svc/branches/?latitude=0&longitude=0&range=20000;

    string value = "foo";

    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://example.com");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", String.Format("example;{0}", value));

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

    var responseJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    Console.WriteLine(responseJson);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you supply the authorization like this? It's how i do it: `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("example;foo")));`

Comment: Its `:` not `;` btw.

Comment: @Alex K, if you are referring to Authorization Value it is ; in my case. It's in a string

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Normally that authorization header has a format as `{scheme} {token}` which is what it is trying to validate with your current code.

Some servers can be configured to accept different formats. To avoid the client validating the standard format use `TryAddWithoutValidation`

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", String.Format("example;{0}", value));
```

which based on your example would have the following request headers

```
Accept application/json
Authorization example;foo
```

Comment: For anyone trying to use google's format of key=blahblahblahblah this works perfect!

Comment: Thank you sweet jesus. I can't tell you how annoying the validation is, I interact with services all the time that require the format, "Authorization: code" with no realm.