# c# Httpclient authorization header without realm

Tags: authorization, httpclient

Many services I wish to authenticate with require the following format:

**authorization: ZCb8p0CIngLSFrBJgA/BYyUZI8zaj3MPg=**

If you add a realm in front of the request, it no longer works.

**authorization: basic ZCb8p0CIngLSFrBJgA/BYyUZI8zaj3MPg=** //doesn't work

Yet, in c# the basic httpclient, I can't add a request header authorization without adding a realm. It always throws an exception, is there a way to add the request authorization header with no realm?

Throws error but this authenticates:

request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "ZCb8p0CIngLSFrBJgA/BYyUZI8zaj3MPg=");

Doesn't throw an error but does not authenticate:

request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "basic ZCb8p0CIngLSFrBJgA/BYyUZI8zaj3MPg=");

Answer (score 1):

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", String.Format("example;{0}", value));

[HttpClient Authorization Header Invalid Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49818959/httpclient-authorization-header-invalid-format/49819111#comment112598638_49819111)